# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365 (On-premise) Opening Web Portal - Error

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

We have installed MS Dynamics CRM 365 as below structure :

2 Frontend (subnet 1)
2 Backend (Subnet 2)
1 Deployment Server (Subnet 2)
2 SQL servers clsuter (subnet 3)

After creating organization and navigate to open the portal http://localhost/test

below error shown in browser :

An error has occurred.

Try this action again. If the problem continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics 365 Community for solutions or contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics 365 Administrator. Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support.

Error in event viewer :

```html
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 12/21/2020 4:17:46 PM 
Event time (UTC): 12/21/2020 1:17:46 PM 
Event ID: 721f2fbf17df4bc2929208fa2b1f7c77 
Event sequence: 11 
Event occurrence: 5 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-132530280420389099 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Program Files\Dynamics 365\CRMWeb\ 
    Machine name: zzzzzzz 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 7400 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: domain\eeeeee 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: CrmException 
    Exception message: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Crm.ServerLocatorService.GetSiteSetting[T](String settingName, Boolean defaultOnError)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.OrganizationSettings.LazyLoadPrivGroup()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.OrganizationSettings.get_PrivilegeUserGroupSid()
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.SecurityLibrary.CheckPrivilegeGroupForOrganization(WindowsIdentity identity, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.SecurityLibrary.TryCheckPrivilegeGroupForOrganization(ExecutionContext context, Boolean checkImpersonatePrivilege)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.VerifyCallerOrigin(ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, Guid callerRegardingObjectId, Int32 invocationSource, Version endpointVersion, OrganizationRequest request, OrganizationInternalRequest organizationInternalRequest)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.DispatchRequest(OrganizationRequest request, OrganizationInternalRequest organizationInternalRequest, SdkResponseDescription responseDescription, SdkPerformanceCounterContext sdkPerformanceCounterContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequestRequestWithInstrumentation(OrganizationRequest request, OrganizationInternalRequest organizationInternalRequest)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<ExecuteRequest>b__0()
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, Guid targetCallerRegardingObjectId, UserType targetUserType, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse, Boolean checkAdminMode)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequestInternal(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, ExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, ExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, ExecutionContext executionContext): Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #87E0490D
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.RetrieveMultipleCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.DataSource.RetrieveMultiple(QueryExpression query, Boolean retrieveLatest, Boolean useSystemUserContext, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Caching.CustomResourceLoader.GetCustomResources(IOrganizationContext context, Int32 cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Caching.CustomResourceLoader.LoadCacheData(Int32 key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<LookupEntry>b__2()
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ResourceManager.CustomResourceManager.TryGetCustomString(String name, CultureInfo culture, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ResourceManager.CustomResourceManager.TryGetCultureString(String name, CultureInfo culture, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ResourceManager.BasicResourceManager.GetCultureString(String name, CultureInfo culture, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Controls.Header..ctor(Boolean isControlHeader)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Controls.BasicHeader..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppHeader..ctor()
   at ASP.test5_default_aspx.__BuildControlcrmHeader()
   at ASP.test5_default_aspx.__BuildControlTree(test5_default_aspx __ctrl)
   at ASP.test5_default_aspx.FrameworkInitialize()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://zzzzzzz/Test5/default.aspx 
    Request path: /Test5/default.aspx 
    User host address: 172.16.xx.xxx 
    User: domain\eeeeee 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: domain\eeeeee 
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 165 
    Thread account name: domain\eeeeee 
    Is impersonating: True 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.RetrieveMultipleCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.DataSource.RetrieveMultiple(QueryExpression query, Boolean retrieveLatest, Boolean useSystemUserContext, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Caching.CustomResourceLoader.GetCustomResources(IOrganizationContext context, Int32 cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Caching.CustomResourceLoader.LoadCacheData(Int32 key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.CreateEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<LookupEntry>b__2()
   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.CrmMultiOrgCacheBase`2.LookupEntry(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ResourceManager.CustomResourceManager.TryGetCustomString(String name, CultureInfo culture, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ResourceManager.CustomResourceManager.TryGetCultureString(String name, CultureInfo culture, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.ResourceManager.BasicResourceManager.GetCultureString(String name, CultureInfo culture, IOrganizationContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Controls.Header..ctor(Boolean isControlHeader)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Controls.BasicHeader..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.AppHeader..ctor()
   at ASP.test5_default_aspx.__BuildControlcrmHeader()
   at ASP.test5_default_aspx.__BuildControlTree(test5_default_aspx __ctrl)
   at ASP.test5_default_aspx.FrameworkInitialize()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
 
 
Custom event details:
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but in case someone will face this, please note that this type of errors are usually logged when the user under which your Application Pool is running does not have required permissions to read Active Directory entries. The easiest way to check if this is your case, add your user to AD admin group and make sure that everything is working. After you can give appropriate permissions instead of admin.

In case your AppPool is running under Network Service account, in AD you`ll need check/change the permissions of your computer where CRM web site is hosted.